# Grails 3 Spring Security Recursive Constructor Invocation

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, spring-security

When I ran s2-quickstart for Spring Security, the domain classes it generated call their default constructors and Intellij 14 is complaining about a `Recursive Constructor Invocation`.  Grails runs fine, but how do I convince IntelliJ that everything is OK?

Also, just out of curiosity, why do these constructors exist at all? I generally prefer to just use the default or map constructor that come out of the box with Groovy. Is that something that can be removed?

```
package com.company.product

import groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode
import groovy.transform.ToString

@EqualsAndHashCode(includes = 'authority')
@ToString(includes = 'authority', includeNames = true, includePackage = false)
class Role implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1

    String authority

    Role(String authority) {
        this()
        this.authority = authority
    }

    static constraints = {
        authority blank: false, unique: true
    }

    static mapping = {
        cache true
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade to Intellij 15. The [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-144371) was fixed a while back.

Alternately, delete the parameterized constructors and use the more verbose Map constructors like you would in other domain classes.

Comment: Thanks Burt.  I appreciate how responsive you always are to Grails questions.

Comment: Hi Burt, I'm using the community edition and still get this error. It's not big deal. So do you know if the fix was only for the paid edition?

Comment: Your best bet is to delete the parameterized constructor and use the regular map constructor.